# Unable to use C++ to read memory image file

Tags: c++, memory-dump

I'm using winpmem to create a memory image.  I would like to create an interface that would allow a user to search for various patterns in the image.  I'm using C++ to open and read the file but I am not able to dump the contents to standard output.  I have tried to use various data types for the variable declaration that is streamed to standard output but I haven't been able to dump a text representation to the screen.  Here is my code:

## include "stdafx.h"

## include "iostream"

## include "iomanip"

## include "fstream"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])

{

double x;

int i = 0;

```
ifstream test;

test.open("C:\\Temp\\mem.raw");

if (!test){

cerr << "Unable to open file datafile.txt";

exit(1);   // call system to stop
```

}

```
while (test >> x) {

cout << i;

cout << ":";

cout << x;

cout << ",";

i++;
```

}

```
test.close();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: seems to be about programming, not RE.

Comment: and the code appears to have lots of errors like declaring an uninitialised double which may contain garbage and prone to rounding errors  not using is_open but comparing ifstream object. then cimparing   the object to a doubke etc

Comment: double was just the last type that i used in my attempt to find the correct type.